# Why is my game (using pygame) so laggy after I blit an image for the background?

Tags: pygame, lag

I wanted a background picture for my game that would always be behind the player character and enemies. I just typed in:

```
background = pygame.image.load("mypicture")
```

at the top of my code, before my running loop. I then blit the image by typing:

```
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

if I blit the image BEFORE the running loop, the game is not laggy at all, but everywhere the player character moves, it leaves an outline that never goes way, [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZNTb.png)
However, if I blit the image DURING the running loop, the previously mentioned tracer effect doesn't happen, but instead, the gamer runs insanely slow.

It's worth mentioning some of the code for my player character:

```
def Player(x, y):
    screen.blit(PlayerImg, (x, y))
```

I call the function at the end of the running loop, right before

```
pygame.display.update
```

. The player is placed at coordinates x, y, which are decided based on input from the keyboard.

Comment: Could you show all of your code

Comment: Try adding convert method: `background = pygame.image.load("mypicture").convert()` and blit it in loop

Comment: Thanks, kaktus_car, it worked. If you said that as an answer instead of a comment, I would check it. What does adding .convert() do exactly?

Comment: @AdamT I wanted to make sure that was the issue. I'll put it as an answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding convert method: `background = pygame.image.load("mypicture").convert()`. This will improve performance. More info here [https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert]
And if you want your background to refresh you must call it inside the loop.